# Python + Selenium, SyntaxError: cannot assign to comparison when creating a list in python

Tags: python, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So i apologise if this is the wrong place for this or if i'm doing anything wrong here but i'm really new to Python and this is literally my first script.

I'm trying to Automate a checkout process with Python + Selenium as a first project and i'm running into an error with the following code.

I've encountered a page during the checkout process where the element i'm trying to select is only selectable using either ClassName and there are more than one of these type of the exact same element on the page, so i thought i'd create a list and choose the element i need (which is the second one) however, i'm now getting the below error.

So it's the first line where i'm trying to create a list of webelements which is throwing up this error:

"SyntaxError: cannot assign to comparison"

```
List<WebElement> elementsList = driver.find_elements(By.className("large"));
elementsList[1].click();
```

If anyone could help me or explain to me where i'm going wrong i'd massively appreciate it.

As i say, i'm new to this so if anything's missing or you need anything else please just let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
elementsList = driver.find_elements(By.className("large"))
elementsList[1].click()
```

You are mixing java and python , python is automatically typed language you don't have to specify the type

Comment: Python wouldn't need semicolons.

Comment: Updated  the answer